# Why is CSS selector 'table tr:not(tr:nth-child(even))' throwing a TypeError?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

Why does this selector work:

```
document.querySelectorAll('table tr:not(:nth-child(even))');
```

While this selector does not (throws a TypeError):

```
document.querySelectorAll('table tr:not(tr:nth-child(even))');
```

```js
var query = (selector) => {
  return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
};
  
try {
  var select_a = 'table tr:not(:nth-child(even))';
  var select_b = 'table tr:not(tr:nth-child(even))';

  query(select_a).forEach((node) => {
    node.style.color = 'red';
  });

  query(select_b).forEach((node) => {
    node.style.color = 'blue';
  });
} catch (e) {
    query('div:nth-child(3)')[0].textContent = e.toString();
}
```

```css
var query = (selector) => {
  return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
};
  
try {
  var select_a = 'table tr:not(:nth-child(even))';
  var select_b = 'table tr:not(tr:nth-child(even))';

  query(select_a).forEach((node) => {
    node.style.color = 'red';
  });

  query(select_b).forEach((node) => {
    node.style.color = 'blue';
  });
} catch (e) {
    query('div:nth-child(3)')[0].textContent = e.toString();
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>row 1 first-name</td>
    <td>row 1 last-name</td>
    <td>row-1 email</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 2 first-name</td>
    <td>row 2 last-name</td>
    <td>row-2 email</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 3 first-name</td>
    <td>row 3 last-name</td>
    <td>row-3 email</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 4 first-name</td>
    <td>row 4 last-name</td>
    <td>row-4 email</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 5 first-name</td>
    <td>row 5 last-name</td>
    <td>row-5 email</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div>Why does select_a work but not select_b?</div>

<div></div>
```

Comment: Why should it work tho? :-)

Comment: What are you trying to select?

Comment: what exactly are you expecting that to do? If the first one works, why don't you use that? Its not working because `is not a valid selector`. The selector syntax engine does not support, whatever it is your trying to do?

Comment: Because `:not()` only takes a “simple selector”, and `tr:nth-child(even)` isn’t one. https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#simple-selectors-dfn _“A simple selector is either a type selector, universal selector, attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.”_

Comment: For the sake of this question I'm not trying to select anything particular at all (I just threw that together as an example). I'm just confused as to why the one selector works while the other doesn't (I'd assume they're supposed to be functionally identical).

Comment: Well then @misorude has your answer. It doesn't work because the spec says this won't work

Comment: I *think* it's because CSS Selector Level 3 syntax restricts the selector in a `:not()` clause to `simple-selector`, which can be *either* a "type" selector (like `tr`) *or* a "subclass" selector. Under that rule (which is kind-of confusing to me), having both `tr` and `:next-child()` is wrong because it's both.

Comment: I think it's an interesting question because it's not at all obvious from the error message what the problem is. Also I think Selector Level 4 syntax relaxes the rule and allows "compound" selectors.

Comment: @Pointy yes, that’s correct, Selectors Level 4 lifts that restriction in favor of a _selector list_. (_“A list of simple/compound/complex selectors is a comma-separated list of simple, compound, or complex selectors. This is also called just a selector list when the type is either unimportant or specified in the surrounding prose”_)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> While this selector does not (throws a TypeError):
>
> ```
> document.querySelectorAll('table tr:not(tr:nth-child(even))');
> ```

`:not()` only takes a “simple selector”, and `tr:nth-child(even)` isn’t one.

https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#simple-selectors-dfn:

> A simple selector is either a type selector, universal selector, attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.

*Either* is the important keyword here. Only one of those selector types is allowed, not combinations of them.