# document.querySelectorAll with conditions inside ":not" not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I try to replace the `.not()` function of jQuery with a native way and unfortunately my use case with `document.querySelectorAll` is not working.

This is what I want to achieve - changing the jQuery selector to vanilla JS:

```
$('#someID').not('.classNameOne > div, .classNameTwo > div, div[class*="-something"] > div')
```

What I tried is using plain and simple this selector:

`document.querySelectorAll("#someID:not(.classNameOne > div, .classNameTwo > div, div[class*="-something"] > div)");`

This throws this error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '#someID:not(.classNameOne > div, .classNameTwo > div, div[class*="-something"] > div)' is not a valid selector.
at <anonymous>:1:10
```

Does one of you know a better way to replace this jQuery function?

Thanks!

Comment: not() allow only *simple* selector .. you cannot put that complex selector inside, still not supported (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54311550/10283047

Comment: _“This is what I want to achieve: […]”_ - please give a proper _verbal_ description of what you actually need, instead of just showing not working code.

Comment: I believe original jQuery code filters element by checking their parents. It is not supported in CSS due to affecting performance in really bad way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
document.querySelectorAll("#someID:not(.classNameOne) > 
div, .classNameTwo > div, div[class*=-something] > div ");
```